# How to operate object structure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {
   skill:{
      eat:true,
      walk:true
   },
   address:{
      home:"where",
      company:"where"
   }
};
```

I can get one item by:

```
tester.activate(obj[skill]);
```

How can I get all the items?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate through the properties of an object with `for ... in`:

```
for (var k in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    var value = obj[k];
    alert("property name is " + k + " value is " + value);
  }
}
```

The call to the "hasOwnProperty" function is there to keep this code from iterating through properties present on "obj" that are actually inherited from the Object prototype.  *Sometimes* you might want to include those, but in this case it's safe to filter them out (I think). (And @sdleihssirhc points out that if you want to be *really* sure, you can use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, k)` )

Comment: Let's see if your guess at the question paid off. (Or perhaps the question was clear to you and just not to me?)

Comment: @Phrogz my fingers are crossed - I agree that the question was completely vague.

Comment: @Phrogz the question was pretty unclear. I interpretted it differently aswell.

Comment: Obligatory note about using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call` for the sufficiently paranoid.

Comment: Good info for a very vague question FTW?!?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the skill you can get

`obj.skill`

If you need the address you can get

`obj.address`

or if you wanted to get the individual data:

```
var eat = obj.skill.eat;
var company = obj.address.company;
```

If you want all the items you can iterate over the structure and push all the items to an array

```
function pushObjToArray(obj, array) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
             if (obj[key] instanceof Array) {
                  pushObjToArray(obj[key], array);
             } else if (obj[key] instanceof Object) {
                  pushObjToArray(obj[key], array);
             } else {
                  array.push(obj[key]);
             }
        }
    }
    return array;
}

var array = [];
pushObjToArray(array, obj);
```

On second thought destroying the keys and pushing all data to an array is pretty useless.

What do you actaully want to do?

You might be looking for something like [`_.flatten`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#flatten)